# Retain for loop information before being sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using discord.js to make a bot; the main functionality is working good and everything but I have a for loop that iterates over an object; I get some information from that object and send it to a channel; the thing is that it send a message for each iteration and it sends them too fast; I've tried using `setInterval()` but it's not working; a better solution would be if I could like retain that information somewhere before it's been sent; this is my code:

```
var stat = [] 
var statNames = ['Speed', 'Special Defense', 'Special Attack', 'Defense', 
                'Attack', 'HP']


for(x in response.stats) {

    stat = {"base": response.stats[x].base_stat,
            "effort": response.stats[x].effort}

    msg.channel.sendMessage(statNames[x] + ": " + stat.base + " - EV: " + stat.effort)
}
```

If I put the `msg.channel.sendMessage` outside of the loop; the message it's not sent properly and stills sends the messages 1 per 1; I just want to send them as only one message; it runs 6 times so there are 6 messages that are being sent too fast and I may get rate limitted by this.

Comment: What does "retain information before it's been sent" mean?  You could easily build an array of objects in your `for` loop if you wanted, but I don't understand what your desired output is here.

Comment: @jfriend00 What I'm trying to say is that each time that the loop runs it send the message to the channel where the bot is; I just don't want to get rate limitted because the loop runs and it sends the message immediately; I said "retain information" in like "Hold the messages until the loop ends and then send them as just 1 message" not 6 separate messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just send one message with a combined string from all the iterations through your loop, then you can just accumulate the results in the `for` loop and send one message with the combined string.

```
var accumulatedResults = [];
for (x in response.stats) {
    // push string into the array to accumulate it
    accumulatedResults.push(statNames[x] + ": " + response.stats[x].base_stat + " - EV: " + response.stats[x].effort);
}
// Now convert the array to JSON and send it all in one message
// The receiving side can use JSON.parse() to turn it back into an array
msg.channel.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(accumulatedResults));
```

You are free to select whatever format you want in the message for sending multiple items in one message.  I used JSON since it's easy to take an array and turn it into a single string for sending and then get back an array on the other end by using `JSON.stringify()` on the sending end and `JSON.parse()` on the receiving end.  But, you could use a comma delimited string if you wanted.  You just have to generate the desired format from the array on one end and then parse the format back into multiple messages on the other end.